# Is there a regex matcher in the test package

Tags: dart, dart-unittest

I have an element like `<span class="percent-complete-bar" style="width: 85%; background: green;"></span>` and I want to check if the `style` attribute contains `width: xx%;` with a regex like `r'width: \d{1,3}%;'`

```
await bar.attributes['style']
```

returns `width: 85%; background: green;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expect(await bar.attributes['style'], matches(r'width: \d{1,3}%;'));
```